# StandardScaler ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (75000,3) (50,) (75000,3)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I need to normalize the eigenvectors for two different shape.After writing this code:

```py
    from sklearn import preprocessing

    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    scaled_df1 = scaler.fit_transform(doc2Vec)
    scaled_df2 = scaler.transform(new_vec)
```

**doc2Vec** = np.zeros((75000, 50)) ; **new_vec** = np.zeros((75000, 3)) .

The **error** is

> File "D:/PycharmProjects/sentiment_analysis_text/Sentiment_analysis-master/project/Word2Vec.py", line 232, in combined_features
>           scaled_df2 = scaler.transform(new_vec)
>         File "D:\PycharmProjects\sentiment_analysis_text\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_data.py", line 806, in transform
>           X -= self.mean_
>       ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (75000,3) (50,) (75000,3)

Notice, I know I'm going to standardise the eigenvectors for the different dimensions, and that's exactly what I'm going to do.How do I fix the code ? Or, how should they be standardised?

Help, please

Comment: This is not possible. If you just want to normalize `new_vec`, then use new instance of `StandardScaler` and `fit_transform` it.

Comment: @AjayDabas :If i want to normalize new_vec ，Combine the two and make it an eigenvector of 53 dimensions. What do I do?,Can you give me a code example?thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `StandardScaler` because `X` given at `transform` should have the same number of the column than the `X` given at `fit`.

Basically, at `fit`, you learnt a vector of mean/std. dev. of dimension (50,) while you try to apply these statistics on your new `X` with only 3 columns.

So if I understand correctly how you want to normalize, you can make your own scaler class:

```py
import numpy as np

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin


class MyScaler(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.means_ = X.mean(axis=0)
        self.std_dev_ = X.std(axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return (X - self.means_[:X.shape[1]]) / self.std_dev_[:X.shape[1]]


X_train = np.random.randn(5, 5)
X_test = np.random.randn(5, 2)

scaler = MyScaler()
print(scaler.fit_transform(X_train))
print(scaler.transform(X_test))
```

and you will get something like:

```py
[[-1.46691268 -1.45361873 -0.45377612  0.49119234 -1.08791771]
 [-0.21413664  0.71465686 -0.29978242  0.58696079 -0.30286673]
 [ 0.5123138   0.17096286 -0.34478627 -1.44547556 -0.51613175]
 [ 1.54792261 -0.76139957 -0.86188385  1.24605112  0.04787813]
 [-0.37918709  1.32939857  1.96022866 -0.8787287   1.85903806]]

[[ 0.38906146  2.27223431]
 [-0.340497   -0.42958738]
 [-0.30017852  1.84465534]
 [ 0.79533469  4.49370725]
 [-0.23766821  1.8216171 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The model is fitted on `doc2Vec = np.zeros((75000, 50))` and then asked to transform `new_vec = np.zeros((75000, 3))`.

**The dimensionality is not the same, thus the error is raised.**

To overcome this, @glemaitre's answer provides a "custom" Scaler.