# Inverse_transform StandardScaler after feature reduction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have performed feature reduction of 105 radiomic features on 207 subjects, so my input has a shape of `(207,105)`. Before any processing, I scaled the feature using `StandardScaler` with `mu=0, sigma=1` since the values of these features have a very large range. After feature reduction, I have 14 features left which are combinations of the 105 features and thus differ from the original values in the input. My output has the shape of `(207,14)`. I want to invert the transformation to perform some statistical analysis with the new values, but since the shapes are different, this gives me an error using `inverse_transform`.

I read something about making [a custom Scaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434397/standardscaler-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes), but this hasn't worked for me. The following is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'H:\input.xlsx') # Load in dataset
scaler = StandardScaler()  # Scale DataFram

X = df.iloc[:,1:] # Radiomic features
y = df.iloc[:,0] # Metastases (1) or not (0)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=40)  # Define StratifiedKFold with 5 splits

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index], X.loc[test_index] #Create train- and test set for radiomic features, stratify based on the ratio of metastases
    y_train, y_test = y.loc[train_index], y.loc[test_index] #Create train- and test set for metastases, stratify based on the ratio of metastases

X_train_radiomic=pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train.iloc[:,6:]))
X_test_radiomic = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_test.iloc[:,6:]))
rank = X_train_radiomic.corr(method='spearman') # performs Spearman rank correlation on radiomic features, discards first column with metastases
agglo=FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=40).fit(rank) # clusters the features into 40 clusters and fits to Spearman rank correlation
X_trainred=pd.DataFrame(agglo.transform(X_train_radiomic)) # Transforms radiomic features based on clustered features
X_testred=pd.DataFrame(agglo.transform(X_test_radiomic)) # Transforms radiomic features based on clustered features
    
X_train_new_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(X_trainred)
X_test_new_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(X_testred)
```

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: You should first use inverse transformation on the reduction class. PCA, for example, has the same inverse_transform method. After this, you be able to go back on scaler.

Comment: I have tried that, see the last two lines. But the `X_trainred` and `X_train_radiomic` do not have the same dimensions and the clustering is performed on the scaled data.